# Div Pushed Down Below Another Div

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked several times, and I have tried everything suggested in other answers, but nothing seems to be working to get my div where it needs to be. Strangely, overnight one of my divs wants to push below the previous div.  The began as floated divs, the first floated to the left and the second to the right, which was displaying fine.  Then, one day it just decided to push the second div down.  I have tried reversing order of the divs and floating right; I have tried min-width; and now I have them as in-line blocks, vertically aligned to the top.  Any suggestions?

```css
    
    /*----------------------------------------------Content Area-------------------------------------*/
    
    #container{padding:30px 0; width: 100%;}
    #container section{margin:0 0 30px 0;}
    #container section.last{margin:0;}
    #container .more{text-align:right; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:smaller; font-weight:bold;}
    
    /* ------Left Column-----*/
    
    #container #left_column{width:25%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
    #container #left_column h2.title{margin-bottom:20px;}
    
    #container #left_column nav{display:block; width:100%; margin-bottom:30px;}
    #container #left_column nav ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
    #container #left_column nav li{margin:0 0 3px 0; padding:0;}
    #container #left_column nav li.last{margin-bottom:0;}
    #container #left_column nav a{display:block; margin:0; padding:5px 10px 5px 20px; color:#666666; background:url("../images/orange_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted    #666666;}
    #container #left_column nav a:hover{color:#FF9900; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
    
    #container #left_column #stats{display:block; width:100%;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul li{margin:0 0 3px 0; display:block; padding:5px 10px 5px 20px; color:#666666; background:url("../images/black_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #FFFFFF; border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul li.odd{float:left;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul li.even{float:right;}
    #container #left_column #stats img{width:100%; height:100px; margin:0 0 15px 0; padding:0px; border:0px solid #666666;}
    
    /* ------Main Content-----*/
    
    #container #content{width:75%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden;}
    #container section{width: 100%;}
```

```html
        
        <div id="container">
        <!-- content body -->
        <aside id="left_column">
          <h2 class="title">Team Functions</h2>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a onClick="clickAction('scripts/calendar.php')">View Team Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a onClick="clickAction('scripts/newteam.php')">Add New Team</a></li>
              <li><a onClick="clickAction('scripts/teamselect.php')">View/Edit Existing Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Project Life</a></li>
              <li class="last"><a href="#">Run Team Diagnostic</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          
          <section id="stats" class="last clear">
            
                  <h2>Quick Team Stats</h2>
                  <img src="images/demo/TeamStat.jpg" alt="">
                
              
                  <h2>Quick Patient Stats</h2>
                  <img src="images/demo/PatientStats.jpg" alt="">
          </section>
        </aside>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- main content -->
        <div id="content" style='margin: 0 auto;'>
          <?php include 'scripts/calendar.php'?>
        </div>
        <!-- / content body -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Which div's aren't fitting how you expect? There is a lot of code there... can you reduce it to just the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Agreed, I put this into a fiddle and it is still hard to make out without all the dependencies in your local environment.

Comment: You could try to give all your block elements a border property with the value border-box. That prevents borders and padding from adding to the elements width and makes it a lot easier to calculate the available width for columns. I you go for the inline-block solution you should also notice that whitespace or linebreaks in the markup between the tags also will be rended as a single non breaking space and therefore adds to the width

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code section to just the elements in question, which are the left 'column div' and the 'content div', which are inside the 'container div'

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*----------------------------------------------Content Area-------------------------------------*/
    
    #container{padding:30px 0; width: 100%;}
    #container section{margin:0 0 30px 0;}
    #container section.last{margin:0;}
    #container .more{text-align:right; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:smaller; font-weight:bold;}
    
    /* ------Left Column-----*/
    
    #container #left_column{width:25%;float:left; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
    #container #left_column h2.title{margin-bottom:20px;}
    
    #container #left_column nav{display:block; width:100%; margin-bottom:30px;}
    #container #left_column nav ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
    #container #left_column nav li{margin:0 0 3px 0; padding:0;}
    #container #left_column nav li.last{margin-bottom:0;}
    #container #left_column nav a{display:block; margin:0; padding:5px 10px 5px 20px; color:#666666; background:url("../images/orange_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted    #666666;}
    #container #left_column nav a:hover{color:#FF9900; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
    
    #container #left_column #stats{display:block; width:100%;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul li{margin:0 0 3px 0; display:block; padding:5px 10px 5px 20px; color:#666666; background:url("../images/black_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #FFFFFF; border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul li.odd{float:left;}
    #container #left_column #stats ul li.even{float:right;}
    #container #left_column #stats img{width:100%; height:100px; margin:0 0 15px 0; padding:0px; border:0px solid #666666;}
    
    /* ------Main Content-----*/
    
    #container #content{width:75%;float:left; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden;}
    #container section{width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <!-- content body -->
        <aside id="left_column">
          <h2>Left Div</h2>
          <h2 class="title">Team Functions</h2>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a onClick="clickAction('scripts/calendar.php')">View Team Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a onClick="clickAction('scripts/newteam.php')">Add New Team</a></li>
              <li><a onClick="clickAction('scripts/teamselect.php')">View/Edit Existing Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Project Life</a></li>
              <li class="last"><a href="#">Run Team Diagnostic</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          
          <section id="stats" class="last clear">
            
                  <h2>Quick Team Stats</h2>
                  <img src="images/demo/TeamStat.jpg" alt="">
                
              
                  <h2>Quick Patient Stats</h2>
                  <img src="images/demo/PatientStats.jpg" alt="">
          </section>
        </aside>
        
        <!-- main content -->
        <div id="content" style='margin: 0 auto;'>
          
          <h2>Right Div</h2>
          <?php include 'scripts/calendar.php'?>
        </div>
        <!-- / content body -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `font-size: 0` on `#container`.  Then add `font-size: 16px` to `#left_column` and `#clear`.  That'll get rid of the white-space caused by breaks new lines and spaces in the html.